# Flashlight App Android

Tags: android, flash, android-camera

I know there's a lot of things out there for an android flashlight app, but they're all outdated. I tried using camera2, but the android developers website doesn't provide any information for enabling the flash, and the only thing close to the flash or "torch" is crossed out. I used some code that I believe is outdated:

```
static Camera cam = Camera.open();
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

But the `setFlashMode` method isn't recognized. I added the permissions in the Manifest, and imported all of the necessary libraries. Or at least I think. Here are my imports:

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
```

Anyway, that's not working out very well. Anybody know what's wrong? And if this method is actually outdated, can anyone explain to me how to turn on a phone's flash with a new working method? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to write

```
Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters()
```

instead of Parameters...?

Anyway, the Camera class is deprecated from android 5.0, (API 21) so you still need this if you want to support android 4.4 and below.

This is the package that should be used from API 21: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

Comment: Hmm, I'll try it out.

Comment: That doesn't really make a difference. `p`'s `setFlashMode` method is still not recognized.

Comment: But what is happening exactly? It does not compile? It compiles but doesn't work?

Comment: It does not compile. It throws an exception. There just isn't a `setFlashMode` method.

Comment: can you post exactly what it says, please? According to other answers on stack overflow your code should work, so it is very strange :/

Comment: I actually haven't run it. But my IDE shows the exception before I run it. It says `cannot resolve symbol 'setflashmode'`.

Comment: I have tried with my IDE (Androi Studio 1.4) and your code works well... maybe try to update your IDE and android sdk and create a new project

Comment: I have Android Studio 1.3. Should that really make a difference?

Comment: no, it sholdn't... but since it's a very strange error, I would try very strange solutions XD (and usually resetting things, works... maybe I would try to clean the project first)

Comment: True, but I have cleaned the project before.